# jQuery object instance reuse with other DOM nodes for performance

Tags: jquery, performance

Please help me find an article I lost track of...

I remember reading a post 2 years ago. It was about an experiment in which the author prevented his function in `.each` from creating new jQuery objects for $(this) each time.

He cached a single jQuery object and he just substituted the DOM node.

I also remember that he described some issues and I would like to read it once again...

**disclaimer:**

1. I'm not talking about caching an object with a selector like `$this=$(this)`. I'm talking about creating a global jQuery instance and saving time that it takes to call $() on a DOM node.
2. I am fully aware that this will break some of jQuery methods for this object. But I remember some of them were working fine in the author's example.

Answer (score 2):

Why do I always find the answers within 5 minutes after asking out of desperation????

It's here:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/

Hope somebody needs that too.